# Regex split string of numbers at finding of Alpha Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

OK Regex is one of the most confusing things to me. I'm trying to do this in Javascript. I have a search field that the user will enter a series of characters. Codes are either:

999MC111

or just

999MC

There is ALWAYS 2 Alpha characters. BUT there may be 1-4 characters at the front and sometimes 1-4 characters at the end.

If the code ENDS with the Alpha characters, then I run a certain ajax script. If there are Numbers + 2 letters + numbers....it runs a different ajax script.

My struggle is I know \d is for 2 digits....but it may not always be 2 digits.

So what would my regex code be to split this into an array. or something.

I think correct regex would be (/^([0-9]+)([a-zA-z]+)([0-9]+)$/

But how do i make sure its ONLY 2 alpha characters in middle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I didnt really care about the middle 2 characters....all that really mattered was the 1st set of numbers and last set of numbers (if any).

So essentially I just needed to deal with digits. So I did this:

```
var lead = '123mc444'; //For example purposes
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
var result = (lead.match(regex));

var memID = result[0]; //First set of numbers is member id
if(result[1] != undefined) {
    var leadID = result[1];
}
```

Comment: [memID, leadID] = lead.match(/\d+/g);

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex `/\d$/` to determine if it ends with a decimal.

`\d` matches a decimal character, and `$` matches the end of the string. The `/` characters enclose the expression.

Try running this in your javascript console, line by line.

```
var values = ['999MC111', '999MC', '999XYZ111']; // some test values

// does it end in digits?

!!values[0].match(/\d$/); // evaluates to true
!!values[1].match(/\d$/); // evaluates to false
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify the exact number of tokens you must use brackets {}, so if you know that there are 2 alphabetic tokens you put `{2}`, if you know that there could be 0-4 digits you put `{0,4}`

```
^([0-9]{0,4})([a-zA-z]{2})([0-9]{0,4})$
```

The above RegEx evaluates as follows:

- 999MC ---> TRUE
- 999MC111 --> TRUE
- 999MAC111 ---> FALSE
- MC ---> TRUE

The splitting of the expression into capturing groups is done by means of grouping subexpressions into parentheses

As you can see in the following link:

http://regexr.com?2vfhv

you obtain this:

> 3 capturing groups:
>   group 1: `([0-9]{0,4})`
>   group 2: `([a-zA-z]{2})`
>   group 3: `([0-9]{0,4})`

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/^\d{1,4}[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{0,4}$/` matches a series of 1-4 digits, followed by a series of 2 alpha characters, followed by another series of 0-4 digits.

This regex: `/^\d{1,4}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/` matches a series of 1-4 digits, followed only by 2 alpha characters.

Comment: ok so how do i split my string into Numbers, Letters, Numbers? I tried var lead = str.split(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/) but lead[0] returns whole number

Comment: You can add discrete capture groups to the above regex, i.e: `/^(\d{1,4})([a-zA-Z]{2})(\d{0,4})$/`, then use JavaScript's string.replace() function to isolate each capture group from the source string into a separate string variable. See this jsFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zXjF9/

Comment: Actually, use this updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/TuEtG/. It only splits the string if a matching regex is found.