# regularExpression for split number and string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following string.

```
var s = "23BE";
```

how to use the regExpression for split this into `23` and `BE`?

I have tried with the code snippet following:

```
var regex = /([A-Z][a-z]+)/;
match = regex.exec(s);
```

Comment: i have use  var s="23BE"like that. i have tried with the code snippet following: var regex = /(\[A-Z][a-z]+)/;match = regex.exec(s);

Comment: Anyway, if you really want to know, here's one way to do it: `var list = s.match(/(\d+|[A-z]+)/g)`

Comment: You might actually want [match](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10): `alert('23BE'.match(/\d+|\D+/g)); // [23,'BE']`.

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8482243/2261259

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
var list = s.match(/(\d+|[A-z]+)/g);  //["23", "BE"]
```